Reticulate py_config() returns error, python310.dll - The specified module could not be found
Here's the code I'm running.
library("reticulate")
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate")
use_virtualenv("r-reticulate", required = TRUE)
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "C:/Users/KyleZengo/r-reticulate/Scripts/python.exe")
py_config()

This returns the error message:
Error: C:/Users/KyleZengo/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python310.dll - The specified module could not be found.

The code runs successfully if the virtual environment "r-reticulate" is created for the first time. If "r-reticulate" already exists, I get the above error message. Why would this happen?
